# Import error for _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried running [this](https://github.com/onurboyar/Retinal-Vessel-Segmentation) neural network and ran into an issue.
`ImportError: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
Can anynone please help? I am on EndeavourOS (arch-based), I have tensorflow, keras and the `cuda-aur` package installed. Here is the full error message for entire context:

```
python3 train_drive.py --train_at_once True \
                       --save_name "experiment_1" \
                       --initial_model_path "/path/to/ckpts.hdf5" \
                       --model_name "vanilla" \
                       --epochs 15 \
                       --train_batch 3 \
                       --val_batch 3 \
                       --already_padded False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kralikl/Programming/OpenScience/Retinal-Vessel-Segmentation/train_drive.py", line 3, in <module>
    from unet.trainers import train_once, train_loop
  File "/home/kralikl/Programming/OpenScience/Retinal-Vessel-Segmentation/unet/trainers.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/kralikl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/home/kralikl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "/home/kralikl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "/home/kralikl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tfe.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *
ImportError: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I ran the command stated in the repository and got error message which I do not understand.

Comment: How exactly did you install tensorflow? It seems your tf installation is completely broken or missing files.

Comment: Hi @ciahoneypot, There is some issue with installed tensorflow or the version mismatch with the python version. Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) to install tensorflow as per your system OS with the correct [TF build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).